# Mounting LDM data partition

Tags: data-recovery

Essentially, the first two LDM partitions on my drive got formatted accidentally (mkfs is pretty... destructive). Windows now detects the drive as "invalid".

`fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 77AFC36F-3CA1-4072-9EE2-0A5A4BFB7301

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1      34       2081       2048     1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sdb2    2082     262177     260096   127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3  262178 1953525134 1953262957 931.4G Microsoft LDM data
```

However, the last partition (the data partiton, /dev/sdb3) did not get overwritten. Is there any way to mount the data partition on Linux (or even Windows) in order to get the data back?

Comment: have you tried [ldmtool](https://medium.com/@jaredrcoopet/mounting-a-microsoft-windows-dynamic-disk-in-ubuntu-18-04-with-ldmtool-548bff84f989) the link is for u18.04 incase that dont work search for that in el.x format

Comment: Just an update: [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) was able to recover the entire partition successfully.